# Cannot Input with checkbox when add label with disclosure

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

Im cannot input with checkbox (value Windows 7&10), only input with checkbox other for show label input field it can be inputted to database

My Sourde code :

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
<label>OS :</label>
<div class="checkbox-list">
    <label for="windows-7" class="form-group col-md-4">
        <input id="windows7" name="os" type="radio" value="Windows 7">
        <span></span>
        Windows 7
    </label>
    <label for="windows-10" class="form-group col-md-4">
        <input id="windows10" name="os" type="radio" class="form-group" value="Windows 10">
        <span></span>
        Windows 10
    </label>


    <!-- other -->
    
    <input id="other" name="os" type="radio" class="form-group" value="Other :">
    <label for="other" class="form-group">Other :</label>

    <div class="other-disclosure">
        <input type="text" name="os" id="os-other" class="form-group col-md-2" placeholder="Isi OS Anda ...">
    </div>
    <!-- other -->
</div>
```

When im remove other part :

```
    <input id="other" name="os" type="radio" class="form-group" value="Other :">
    <label for="other" class="form-group">Other :</label>

    <div class="other-disclosure">
        <input type="text" name="os" id="os-other" class="form-group col-md-2" placeholder="Isi OS Anda ...">
    </div>
```

My input field checkbox (windows 7&10) no problem, it can be inputted to database.

Im using laravel framework

what happened, what sould i do ?